# Cake.Frosting получить последний коммит с удаленного репозитория

Tags: c#

Делаю сборку проекта на Cake.Frosting, все готово но осталась одна проблема: нужно из удаленного репозитория получить атрибуты последнего коммита. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

В общем из С# запустили cmd, передали команду для git, получили вывод. Проблема решена.